# File in the classpath not being published (Eclipse + JBoss AS)

Tags: eclipse, jboss, osx-mavericks, instrumentation, activejdbc

I am working in an ActiveJDBC project that requires an instrumentation step before the build in order to do the entity mapping. I did this by adding a script that generates an activejdbc.properties at the classpath.

The build part is fine and the file is being properly generated in the workspace. However, when I publish the project the file is being packed in the WAR file (all the other classes are fine though).

It is a simple dynamic web project, no changes in the build or classpath besides the instrumentation step. I am using:
- OS X Mavericks.
- Eclipse Juno.
- Maven 3.
- JBoss AS 7.
- JRE 1.6.

I used the following tutorial: http://javalite.io/eclipseIntegration

Can you guys give me a hint on whats going on? There is no error or warning in console...

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `activejdbc_models.properties` file. This file will be produced by instrumentation process and will be placed at the root of your classpath, usually target/classes. Please see if it is there. If it is there, it will be placed at the root of your war file: war_root/WEB-INF/classes. Unpack your war file and see if it is there. If not, something is wring in how you create a war file.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the name. The file is being generated under target/classes, but it doesnt end up in war/web-inf/classes. If I put it there manually, it works fine. Somehow it is ignoring it during the publishing.

Comment: something is wrong with your build process. If file is there before the build, but not after, you need to look into that

Answer (score 0):

I went through the whole process again and, after a lot of attempts, I changed the configuration in the instrumentation builder to refresh resources recursively upon completion and it started working. Its on Proj Properties >> Builders >> Edit (on instrumentation builder) >> Refresh tab.

It seems to be working now, but I'll try to map more entities to check if its really ok.